# Doubt in the proof of every natural number is either $1,$ prime or product of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> [image: proof]

Sorry if I'm being daft but could somebody please explain the logic used to finish the proof at the bit "it follows that this proposition is true for both $c$ and $d\ldots$" Thank you!

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: Isn't this statement vacuously true? If $n$ is not $1$, and it's not a product of two other natural numbers, then call it prime. Now every $n>1$ is either the product of two natural numbers or it isn't. If it is, call it composite. If it isn't, call it prime. It's unclear to me what the purpose of this proof is. It would make more sense if the notion of a "prime number" has already been defined somewhere before this.

Comment: @Myridium No, it's not vacuous. Note that the third case isn't "composite" but "product of primes" - basically, the thing that needs proving is that the Euclidean algorithm terminates (you can't keep factoring and factoring a number forever).

Comment: @Myridium My guess is that the notion of "prime number" *has* already been defined; how would the proposition make sense otherwise?

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Okay, alright. Each time you factor you at least divide by $2$ so eventually it's going to terminate... honestly it just upsets me to see such a confusing proof for such an obvious fact.

Comment: Yes that's right, preceding this I was given the definition that each prime has only 2 divisors. I just don't understand the bit at the end of this proof talking about minimality and how it links to the definition of a prime proves the proposition.

Comment: @Myridium "Each time you factor you at least divide by $2$ so eventually it's going to terminate..." That needs induction to prove!

Comment: Since m is the smallest number for which the proposition is false, and c and d are less than m, the proposition is true for c and d. But c and d are not 1. This means each is either prime or a product of prime numbers. So then m can be written as a product of primes (just take the "prime factorizations" of c and d and multiply them together), which contradicts our assumption that the proposition is false for m.

Comment: @Useless Ahhh that makes sense! I knew it was just a case of getting a slight rewording. Thank you!

Comment: @Myridium This is actually important - think about the notion of "prime" in arbitrary rings ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first let's see what we know *without* assuming that $m$ is the least counterexample to the proposition:

- Since $m$ is a counterexample to the proposition, $m$ can't be prime.
- Since $m$ isn't prime, it has some divisor $c$ other than $m$ and $1$.
- Since $c$ divides $m$, the ratio $m\over c$ is a natural number - call it "$d$." And $c$ isn't $m$ or $1$, we know that $d$ isn't $m$ or $1$ either (why?).

OK, now we know that $m=cd$, and this means $c, d<m$. Now:

> What does $c, d<m$ tell us?

---

**Now** we use the assumption that $m$ is the *least* counterexample to the proposition - so this tells us exactly that $c$ and $d$ **aren't** counterexamples to the proposition! That is (since neither is $1$) each of $c$ and $d$ is either prime or a product of primes. This lets us decompose $m$ itself as a product of primes - namely, "stick together" the product-of-primes representations of $c$ and $d$.

Remember, if $$c=p_1\times...\times p_a\quad \mbox{ and }\quad d=q_1\times...\times q_b$$ then $$m=p_1\times...\times p_a\times q_1 \times ...\times q_b.$$

Comment: Please note that the proposition should have been stated for  _irreducible_ factors rather than for _primes_. The definition of _prime_ is stronger ($p\ne\pm1$ and if $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$) and the fact that in the ring of integers every irreducible is prime is a theorem (i.e., requires a proof)

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia While that's true, many textbooks (including I suspect the OP's) do define "prime" as "has no nontrivial divisor." Which is unfortunate, but I thought it better to use the language the OP is familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Since $m$ is the minimum counterexample. Therefore, the statement of the proposition is true for any number strictly less than $m.$ Thus, it is true for both $c$ and $d.$

So, we have that $c$ is either $1$ or prime of a product of primes.

**Case $1:c=1.$** Then $m=d$ which is either $1$ or prime of a product of primes.

**Case $2: c$ is prime.** Then $m$ is the product of a prime and $d.$ Since, the statement is true for $d$ also, therefore $m$  will be either prime of a product of primes.

**Case $3: c$ is a product of primes.** Again, since the statement holds for $d$ also, therefore, in this case, $m$ will be a product of primes.

But, since $m$ was a counterexample, so in either cases we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I understand that in this context people refer to *prime* as a synonymous of *irreducible*, these two concepts are not generally the same.

Irreducibility refers to the impossibility of having proper factors (i.e., factors other than *unities* and *associates*). However, primality refers to a stronger property by which $p$ is *prime* if it is not a unity and

$$
   p | ab \implies p | a \text{ or } p | b.
$$

It is easy to see that prime $\implies$ irreducible. However, the converse may not hold true in certain rings (e.g., $2\cdot3=(1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$).

For integers, however, both notions coincide because of the Euclid Algorithm that allows the $\gcd(a,b)$ to be written as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. In fact, if $p$ is irreducible and doesn't divide $a$, then $\gcd(p,a)=1$ (why?). Thus $1=sa + tp$ and therefore $b = sab + tpb$. Now, since $p$ is a divisor of $ab$, it must also divide $b$.